# Multiple methods named 'objectAtIndex:' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a table on my ios app that shows last tweets, however after updating my app to 64bit architecture I'm getting four times the following error: `multiple methods named 'objectAtIndex:' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes error.`

This is the relevant part of the code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didHoldRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {    

if ([NXCatchall isiPad]) {

    NSDictionary *tweet = [twitterHandler getTweetForArrayIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSDictionary *urls = [[tweet objectForKey:@"entities"] objectForKey:@"urls"];

    urlDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    for (int i=0; i<urls.count; i++) {
        NSString *displayName = [[urls valueForKey:@"display_url"] objectAtIndex:i];
        NSURL    *url         = [NSURL URLWithString:[[urls valueForKey:@"expanded_url"]objectAtIndex:i]];
        [urlDict setValue:url forKey:displayName];

    }

    if (urlDict.count != 0) {


    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] init];
    [actionSheet setTitle:@"Open in Safari"];
    [actionSheet setDelegate:self];

for (int i=0; i<urlDict.count; i++) {
    // NSString *key = [[dict allKeys] objectAtIndex:i];
    //Yes it's ugly, it works at runtime. Deal with it.
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:[[urlDict valueForKey:(NSString*)
                                      [[urlDict allKeys]objectAtIndex:i]]absoluteString]];
}
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"heldTweetWithInfo" object:self userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:actionSheet forKey:@"actionSheet"]];


    }
}
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSDictionary *tweet = [twitterHandler getTweetForArrayIndex:indexPath.row];

if ([NXCatchall isiPad]) {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"selectedTweetNotification" object:self userInfo:tweet];

}

NSDictionary *urls = [[tweet objectForKey:@"entities"] objectForKey:@"urls"];

urlDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (int i=0; i<urls.count; i++) {
        NSString *displayName = [[urls valueForKey:@"display_url"] objectAtIndex:i];
        NSURL    *url         = [NSURL URLWithString:[[urls valueForKey:@"expanded_url"]objectAtIndex:i]];
        [urlDict setValue:url forKey:displayName];

    }
```

Affected lines start with **NSString** & **NSURL**

Comment: Change your uses of `valueForKey:` to `objectForKey:` unless you have a specific need to use KVC.

Comment: I'll get the same error changing `valueForKey:` to `objectForKey:`

Comment: What does [urls valueForKey:@"expanded_url"] return?

Comment: I'm not really sure as I haven't written the original code

Answer (score 1):

Try casting it into NSArray. My guess is that some other class declares objectAtIndex.

```
      NSString *displayName = [(NSArray *)[urls valueForKey:@"display_url"] objectAtIndex:i];
      NSURL    *url         = [NSURL URLWithString:[(NSArray *)[urls valueForKey:@"expanded_url"]objectAtIndex:i]];
```

Comment: If I do that then I'll get this error: 
`ld: library not found for -lPods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`